# Runtime Setting Embedded in Exe

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, embed

I have the following in my App.Config but would like to embed this into my console application so that the config file isn't required for the exe. How is this possible?

```
<runtime>
  <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false;Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false" />
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call the `SetSwitch` method:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling", false);
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths", false);
```

See the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appcontext.setswitch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this. I need this to run on XP however, and this specifically targets .Net 4.6. Any other methods of doing this?

Comment: I think the `AppContext` stuff was introduced in .NET 4.6. So, it doesn't matter if you do it in code or in the config. It won't work below .NET 4.6. You will have to go without these switches on XP or find an alternative way...